# Teen fiction, 2 boys find a boat burial

Tags: story-identification

I think I read this book around 1990-1992-ish. I don't recall the title or author's name. It was teenage fiction.

Two boys find a viking/Anglo-Saxon boat burial. The
burial becomes the site of an archaeological dig. Evidence is uncovered
of grave robbers, some of whom may have died at the grave after having
taken something. There is a suggestion that the buried ship and it's
occupant can't continue to the after world because of the grave robbing.
I think there may have been a curse alluded to.

Eventually the shed
covering the burial burns down and one of the boys stays inside. There
is a description where the boy inside is steering the boat through the
flames to the after world. At the very end, the other boy is talking
about missing his dead friend.